# Asynchronous (awaitable) WriteAllBytes in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous

So, I'm trying to do an asynchronous write of some data to the drive. It seems like .NET doesn't have an Awaitable async version of this. This is what I came up with:

```
Public Async Function WriteAllBytesAsync(path As String, data() As Byte) As Task
    Await Task.Run(
         Sub()
             File.WriteAllBytes(path, data)
         End Sub)
End Function
```

Would this work properly?

Comment: @AlexH Codereview is for code that already works. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @AlexH This question would be locked the instant it arrived on Code Review. Do not suggest migrating if you're not familiar with the specific SE.

Comment: @Mast / jacwah Im very sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It would *work* - as in, operate correctly. However, it's not an ideal solution for every scenario. In particular, this would be a poor solution on ASP.NET, where `Task.Run` should be avoided; or for a general-purpose library, where the method would be advertising an asynchronous signature but implement it using "fake asynchrony" (blocking a thread pool thread).

So, I'd say that if this code is just in a UI or Console app, it would be OK. Otherwise, I'd change it to use true asynchrony (i.e., a loop calling `WriteAsync`).